# Getting error on installing a python package regarding mysqlclient

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, django, pip

I am currently working on a new project. Trying to install the requirements using pip but getting this error. Using python version 3.6.9

This is the error message I am getting.

```
Collecting en-core-web-sm@ https://github.com/explosion/spacy-models/releases/download/en_core_web_sm-3.4.0/en_core_web_sm-3.4.0-py3-none-any.whl
  Downloading https://github.com/explosion/spacy-models/releases/download/en_core_web_sm-3.4.0/en_core_web_sm-3.4.0-py3-none-any.whl (12.8 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 12.8 MB 5.9 MB/s            
ERROR: mysqlclient-1.4.6-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.
```

Error log on - https://dpaste.org/U7F7g

Any help would be highly appreciated and thank you in advance to anyone who looks into this.

Comment: If you are using windows, installation instructions are provided which may work.
https://pypi.org/project/mysqlclient/

Comment: check your os and instruction set, if it's not windows and x86_64, then you should try to build it from source

Comment: @nnzzll, I am on ubuntu 20.04. and using python version 3.6, please check this error log if it helps https://dpaste.org/U7F7g

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to install a different version of the mysqlclient wheel that is compatible with your version of Python.

Comment: Hi @robotiaga, how can I install a different version of mysqlclient wheel in linux ?

Comment: first try,
apt-get install python3-dev

apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev